# Java JNLP Desktop Shortcut and Icon

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application, jnlp

Java integrates nicely with the user's desktop OS through JNLP.
Not only does my software show up as a desktop icon, but it is listed as an installed program in the control panel (Windows 7).  I was also able to get the JNLP file to auto-configure file association. Now if the user double-clicks a file saved by my program (a pxml file), the program launches.  JNLP makes this excellent desktop integration happen smoothly through the web launch.
One issue remains: How do I get my program to load the data file that the user double-clicks?  The pxml file is given the same icon as my program, and JNLP created the file association, so windows knows to launch my software when the user tries to open the pxml file.  But how does my program know to OPEN that file when it starts?

Below is part of the JNLP file for reference, taken from [Proctinator.com](http://www.proctinator.com/dist/clientDownload.htm)

```
<jnlp  spec="6.0+" codebase="http://proctinator.com/dist" >
  <information>
    <title>The Proctinator</title>
    <vendor>Smart Software Solutions, INC.</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://proctinator.com"/>
    <description kind="short">The Proctinator exam scheduling software</description>
    <icon kind="splash" href="splashScreen.jpg" />
    <icon kind="shortcut" href="bigP.jpg" />
    <offline-allowed/> 
    <association extensions="pxml" mime-type="application/pxml"/>
    <shortcut online="false">
      <desktop/>
    </shortcut>
  </information>
  <resources>    <j2se version="1.6+"/> ...  </resources>
<application-desc main-class="thornworks.proctor.GUI"/>
```

Comment: Never tried this before, but doesn't this get just get passed as a parameter to your main() method?

Comment: That JNLP is invalid (and malformed), try checking it using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: Andrew - The XML above is not the whole file.  Are you sure that JaNeLA is up to date and recognizes new syntax introduced with 1,6?

Comment: @mikera After I wrote this, I thought of the same thing.  I'll have to write some code to test that theory. Is this how Windows handles file association application-launch - as command line parameters?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is up to date.  OTOH I cannot now see what made me say that was malformed.  My bad.  Why?  Are you getting any errors or warnings?  It is common for users to misunderstand the messages, some of which I have no control over.

Comment: The file does not generate any errors or warnings.  The desktop shortcut is created (if the client system permits it) and the file and icon association seems to work too.  I think mikera's comment might actually be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open an associated file with a Java Web Start launch, use the second element of the parameter array passed to `main(String[] args)`. The first element will be "-open" when you launch the application by double-clicking a file and args[1] stores the file path of the file we want to open on startup.  This feature really makes the Java app feel like a native desktop application.

I couldn't find this in the JNLP documentation.

Here is a sample main method that implements this feature.  FileFunction is a class with static methods for application file I/O.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUI win = new GUI(null);
    if(args.length==2) {
        win = new GUI(null);
        StringBuilder params = new StringBuilder();
        for(String s : args) {
            params.append(s);
            params.append("\n");
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, params);
        try {
            FileFunction.loadList(new FileInputStream(new File(args[1])));
        }
        catch(IOException ioe) {
            FileFunction.showFileError(ioe);
        }
    }
```